# Filter an array of objects and return an array of objects where the value of a key appears x times

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have this array of objects that I would like to filter by count of store_id.

```
[{
ingredient_id: "lim1",
status: true,
store_id: "1"
},
{
ingredient_id: "lem1",
status: true,
store_id: "1"
},
{
ingredient_id: "lem1",
status: true,
store_id: "5"
}]
```

If the value of x was 2 the output I would like is:

```
[{
ingredient_id: "lim1",
status: true,
store_id: "1"
},
{
ingredient_id: "lem1",
status: true,
store_id: "1"
}]
```

Because store_id:'1' appears twice

However if the value of x was 3 I would like it to return empty.

Everywhere I've looked for answers only shows me how to remove duplicates rather than only returning them and trying the opposite of those hasn't helped me.

Comment: Which key are you counting? `store_id`?

Comment: Great point, yes. Will update

Comment: What is the output if your input array has another object such as `{ingredient_id: "lem1", status: true, store_id: "5"}` and `x` is 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this problem by generating an object with counts of each of the `store_id` values, and then filtering your input array on whether the count of each entries `store_id` matches the `x` value:

```js
const data = [{
    ingredient_id: "lim1",
    status: true,
    store_id: "1"
  },
  {
    ingredient_id: "lem1",
    status: true,
    store_id: "1"
  },
  {
    ingredient_id: "lem1",
    status: true,
    store_id: "5"
  }
];

const counts = data.reduce((c, v) => {
  c[v.store_id] = (c[v.store_id] || 0) + 1;
  return c;
}, {});

const x = 2;

const result = data.filter(v => counts[v.store_id] == x);
console.log(result);
```